# Lotus Notes 8.5.3 - Add a Column with all Folders one Document is in to a custom Mail View

Tags: email, view, lotus-notes, directory

in Lotus Notes 8.5.3, I created a custom mail view, showing only e-mails that comply with some filter criterion.

Now, I'd like to add a column to this view, that shows for each e-mail-document all the e-mail-folders in which it is filed. This shall be just like the column "Folder" in the "All Documents" view. E.g., for one e-mail that was added to several folders, all of those folders shall be shown in this column.

Thank you for your help
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column in the $All view uses a function called @WhichFolders. The documentatation says this about it:

> @WhichFolders is intended for use only as a column formula in the mail template.
>
> This function is effective only when the view is open in the UI and the outline pane on the left is visible.

The documentation does *not* say that you need to enable the Folder References property for the mail database - which involves adding some special views , but in case you do need that (I don't think you do, but in case you also need programmatic access to the folder data in addition to just seeing it in the column) you can learn about that [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21092899).

Comment: The Column Formula `@WhichFolders` does the job. _Thank you, Richard!_

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StacOverflow. Since it helped you, please consider upvoting and accepting my answer.